# Create indices for two time series values in R

Tags: r

I am trying to compare two time series in R to assess how closely they correlate by plotting them on a line graph. To avoid having two separate axes for the data, I want to make an index of each value, to plot the changes of the values since date X by plotting the indices rather than the raw data.

Data looks like this:

```
Table 1.
Month   A      B
Jan     3883   151831
Feb     3626   154070
Mar     4346   163550
Apr     3439   155674
```

Desired output looks like this:

```
Table 2.
Month   A      A.index   B        B.index
Jan     3883   100       151831   100
Feb     3626   93.38     154070   101.47
Mar     4346   111.92    163550   107.71
Apr     3439   88.56     155674   102.53
```

I can achieve this in excel by exporting table 1 to excel and adding a column for A.index and B.index and using a calculation to determine the change from the the index number of 100. Assuming that A is in column B, then I simply:

```
=(cn)/c$2*100
```

Where cn is column C row n, c$2 is the original value and 100 is the index number.

However, I'd like to know how to achieve the same thing in R, so that I can wrap it in a function, as this will be something I need to do semi-regularly.

Cheers Tom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `tranform()`, this is simple as can be. The key line is actually pretty similar to the Excel code, and should be self-explanatory.

```
df <- read.table(text="Month   A      B
Jan     3883   151831
Feb     3626   154070
Mar     4346   163550
Apr     3439   155674", header=T)

df <- transform(df, A.index=100*A/A[1], B.index=100*B/B[1])
df
#   Month    A      B   A.index  B.index
# 1   Jan 3883 151831 100.00000 100.0000
# 2   Feb 3626 154070  93.38141 101.4747
# 3   Mar 4346 163550 111.92377 107.7185
# 4   Apr 3439 155674  88.56554 102.5311
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a more scalable / general solution is to use the `apply()` function to iterate through all of your columns, regardless of how many columns you have:

```
x <- matrix(c(3883, 151831, 3626, 154070, 4346, 163550, 3439, 155674),
            ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, c("A", "B")))

apply(x, 2, function(y) 100 * y / y[1])

             A        B
[1,] 100.00000 100.0000
[2,]  93.38141 101.4747
[3,] 111.92377 107.7185
[4,]  88.56554 102.5311
```

You can obviously `cbind()` this information back to your original data if needed, or just plot this directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `sweep` function, which is similar to `apply` and works also very good with time series

```
df <- ts(data = data.frame(A = c(3883, 3626, 4346, 3439), 
                        B = c(151831,154070, 163550, 155674)),
        frequency = 12)


sweep(df, MARGIN = 2, STATS = df[1,], FUN = "/") * 100


             A        B
Jan 1 100.00000 100.0000
Feb 1  93.38141 101.4747
Mar 1 111.92377 107.7185
Apr 1  88.56554 102.5311
```

In the case that df is not a time series but a data.frame one has to put `STATS = as.numeric(df[1,])` otherwise it will return an error.